# HashMultimap cannot be resolved to a type?

Tags: java, hashmap, guava, multimap

this thing with Multimaps starts to btoher me. 
This is how i create the Map.

```
Map<String, Multimap<String,Values>> valuesMap = new HashMap<String, Multimap<String, Values>>();
```

then the second inner Map is this.

```
Multimap<String, Values> mm = new HashMultimap.create();
```

But after compiling I get this failure message: HashMultimap.create cannot be resolved to a type

I have all imports of guava included. What I dont understand, Intellisense recognises Hashmap but not Hashmultimap. I hope somebody can give me a tip, I am searching for hours.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`create`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/20.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/HashMultimap.html#create--) is a `static` method. Remove the `new` keyword

```
Multimap<String, Values> mm = HashMultimap.create();
```

Comment: omg...I hate it, if you search for hours and the solution is so simple :D thank you very much. I will accept your answer in exactly 7 minutes.